# Fastboot unlock failed

Tags: fastboot, bootloader, bootloader-lock, nokia-6

I have a Nokia 6 and whenever I try to unlock my device I am facing error.

The command

```
sudo fastboot oem unlock
```

The result

```
(remote: oem unlock is not allowed)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nokia phones do not currently allow unlocking of the bootloader. So, you cannot unlock the bootloader even if you have enabled "OEM Unlocking" in *Developer Options*.

It doesn't unlock because Nokia Mobile has locked them with an encrypted key and it is needed to gain temporary access of complete a full-unlock of the bootloader.

There is an [unofficial (and paid) method](https://www.techmesto.com/buy-nokia-bootloader-unlock-key/) available which you can use if unlocking is important for you.

Nokia/HMD are also showing some signs that they will allow unlocking of the bootloader. Official unlocking is enabled for Nokia 8 device owners and chances are that this will be expanded to the other phones in the future.

Comment: can i unlock it if i flash stock nougat firmware because it is written that they have implemented this in August 2018 security patch

Comment: @BhavukSharma With August 2018 release, they blocked the unofficial unlocks. So, yes, if you flash Nougat, you can unlock if after purchasing that unofficial key :)

Answer (score 0):

HMD has not yet allowed the bootloader unlock of Nokia 6, so you have no chance :(